# Run php composer.phar install Error

Tags: php, vagrant, installation, composer-php

I am trying to install composer while SSHed on a vagrant machine. Whenever I run php composer.phar install I get the following error:

```
vagrant@precise64:/vagrant$ php composer.phar install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for doctrine/migrations dev-master -> satisfiable by doctrine/migrations[dev-master].
    - doctrine/migrations dev-master requires php ^5.5|^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.4.45) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

I do not know what to do with the first 'installation request for doctrine...' problem and when I check run php -v I have php 5.5.27 installed. I have also tried sudo php composer.phar install. Any insight?

Comment: `php5 -v` will be the same? .. I suggest you have 2 different php version, but first can be accessed inside `/usr/bin` and second inside `/usr/local/bin` (or something similar location).  Usually `/usr/bin/php` is a symlink. And, for example, you have `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:...` your system search `php` inside `/usr/local/bin`, but not found.. search next inside `/usr/bin`, found and run... script can run `php5` instead `php`.. the system found  `php5` inside the first PATH location `/usr/local/bin`.. It's just weird suggestion. It can be wrong.

Comment: when I run php -v in the project directory it is running php 5.5.27. However after I run the vagrant environment by running vagrant up it runs 5.4.45. How do I upgrade php while inside an environment?

Comment: There is likely a `platform` section in the `composer.json` overriding the PHP version.

Comment: @mle33 ouch... It seems you have version 5.5 on host platform, and 5.4 inside the vagrant one. Just update your php inside the vagrant vm .. sudo su , apt-get update , apt-get upgrade. If there is no php5.5 in the repo, append dotdeb repository. How to do that you can read [**here**](https://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/), it's like regular debian update. But I don't know will it works for Ubuntu or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your box, precise64 (Ubuntu 12.04) likely has an outdated version of PHP on it.

There are a couple of ways you could approach upgrading PHP. For the sake of simplicity and modularity, we will focus just on upgrading PHP.

SSH into the box:

```
vagrant ssh
```

The version of PHP you need is not available by default in the Precise repos IIRC. Add a PPA which has an updated version:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php5
sudo apt-get update
```

Remove existing PHP:

```
sudo apt-get purge php5
```

Check the install candidate, it should be at least 5.5 (it's `5.5.33+` for me as of this post):

```
sudo apt-cache policy php5
```

Install the updated version of php5:

```
sudo apt-get install php5
```

And now `composer` should work just fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are several PHP are installed on your machine. Use the below command to check the first php in your PATH environment.

```
which php
```

Comment: when I run php -v in the project directory it is running php 5.5.27. However after I run the vagrant environment by running vagrant up it runs 5.4.45. When i run which php both scenarios result in /usr/bin/php. How do I upgrade php while inside an environment specifically the vagrant environment? Any tips? @Vigikaran